# Cannot open file with absolute path in Systemd Service

Tags: systemd, services, c, c++

I have a .service which running my C++ application. My path is absolute path. It works when it is launch via command line but fails to open file when lauch via a systemd service. Output in service is error 13 (permission denied) although my service run as root.

Service status:

```
● myservice.service - myservice
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-14-11 08:03:54 PST; 6s ago
 Main PID: 105618 (myservice)
 CGroup: /system.slice/myservice.service
         105618 /etc/EPR/bin/manage
Dec 11 08:03:54 BK systemd[1]: Started myservice.
Dec 11 08:03:55 BK systemd[1]: Unable to write log to file 13
```

C++ code:

```
void write_log_to_file(string file_name, string content){
    ofstream handle_file(file_name, ios::app);
    if(handle_file.is_open()){
        string log = string("[") + dkstd::time::get_time_as_string("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") + string("]: ") + content;
        handle_file << log << endl;
        handle_file.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to write log to file " << file_name << errno << endl;
}
```

Service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Manage

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/etc/EPR/bin/manage
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Have you any idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: Do you have selinux enabled? systemd will not be able to start a binary unless it is in the directory where services are supposed to be (e.g. /usr/bin/, /usr/local/bin/, etc.), or you have to change the type of your binary to be allowed to be started with systemd. Oh. From your description, I can see, that the service is started, but it cannot write a log file. The error message should write the log filename and errno. It says only `Unable to write log to file 13`. I guess 13 is errno. Where is the filename?

Comment: My selinux enabled. My binary run normally unless writing log. Filename binary: /etc/EPR/bin/manage. Filename log: /etc/EPR/log/log.txt

Comment: i called write_log_to_file function with absolute path parameter.

Comment: Why does then your program output the error message without a file name? According to your source there should be a file name in `Unable to write log to file 13` like these `Unable to write log to file /etc/EPR/log/log.txt13`, but it is not. Therefore, I guess your program does not have a filename for log file. And I would recommend to put log file in `/var/log/`. Not in `/etc/`.